# web audio API and filter coefficients

Tags: signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm learning to use the [web audio api](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#BiquadFilterNode-section) to synthesize and process sound. I see there's a [BiquadFilterNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#BiquadFilterNode-section) class I can use, but it only allows to specify one of the filter types defined (`"lowpass",   "highpass", "bandpass", "lowshelf", "highshelf", "peaking", "notch", "allpass"`) and control it through the meta parameters of such filters: `Q`, `gain` and `center-frequency`.

Is there a way to specify the actual coefficients of the digital filter? In other words, for a filter of the form:

```
       b_0 + b_1*z^(-1) + b_2*z^(-2)
H(z) = -----------------------------
       1 + a_1*z^(-1) + a_2*z^(-2)
```

can I somehow directly specify the values of `b_0, b_1, b_2, a_1, a_2`?

I ask because although the predefined filter types are very handy, they don't necessarily cover all the use cases. By specifying the coefficients it would be possible to implement first-order filters, parametric sections, etc.

Comment: This seems not to be possible. But [here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#BiquadFilterNode) is written `Multiple BiquadFilterNode filters can be combined to form more complex filters`. Perhaps that helps..otherwise you have to implement the filter by your own.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @redreggae. I know I could implement filters directly in JavaScript (using [ScriptProcessorNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode-section)), but this is very inefficient and I'm pretty sure that everything needed is already implemented at a low level in the `BiquadFilterNode`. Is just a matter of exposing the coefficients through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible, but is a simple API to add.

At the least, it's clear we need to add support for 1st-order filters.

Comment: Well, if the man behind WebAudio tells me is not possible, I guess is not.
I know you probably have tons of more important stuff to work on WebAudio, but for what it's worth, count with my vote on exposing the filter coefficients directly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.  There's a proposal for an entirely separate DSP API in the WG, but it's not completely baked yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! I didn't know there's a proposal for a DSP API, but that sounds cool.
That said, it might be an overkill to have to use yet another API for this particular use case, as this could be easily added to the webAudio API (see @ChrisRogers comment above)